# Remotely restore a Centos 7 backup done with rsync

Tags: centos, backup, rsync, restore

I have a server running CentOS 7. I did a backup to my local computer at home, using `rsync` (-aAXvhr and --exclude the "classic suggested folders"). So far so good.

I messed up things on my server and I wanted to restore my backup. But here I started having doubts and finally problems.

I read as many articles/questions as I could, but I didn't find a solution (probably because I'm a newbie). Well, at the end I restored (with rsync) my backup folders to my server (target /) and I rebooted my server. GAME OVER...

I had to ask my hosting company to reset my server and now I have to configure everything from scratch.

Well, it's not a huge problem because I'm still in the "testing mode", but my plan is to migrate here a website that's actually running on another hosting.

So, at the end of the day, I do need to understand what's the best solution for REMOTELY restore on my server a backup I did with rsync to my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Server Fault!

I would recommend that you only backup data that is specific to the databases, applications and config files running on a server. I don't backup the entire root or boot partitions, namely because those things don't include the "important data". I can very easily spin up a new virtual server with the same operating system, and restore my files to that new server.

Comment: Then you are suggesting to backup DATABASES (with mysqldump) and applications / config files (with rsync)? Isn't there a solution based only on one backup/restore command?